Prevent all devices from waking computer when all devices are set to not wake computer
I'm ready to go nuclear on this. I've read every guide I can get my hands on, performed every step to attempt to get my computer to stop waking from sleep from no other way except the power button. When I use powercfg /devicequery wake_armed it reports back as NONE. Yet, when I put my computer to sleep, give it a solid minute wait for it to actually sleep. I left click the mouse and the computer wakes up. I should mention, I'm using a Surface Pro 2 on Win10 Pro and it is a plugged in USB mouse. I'm at my wits end to solving this. Again, I want this computer to wake up ONLY from the power button, period!

Have you checked motherboard BIOS power settings?
